# Polymer core-meta is already registered

Tags: html, import, bower, polymer, web-component

I'm building an application with Polymer, and I'm having trouble creating my own component.  The component I'm building is a login prompt.

```
<link rel="import" href="/static/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/static/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="/static/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">

<polymer-element name="login-prompt" attributes="">

  <template>
    <paper-input label="Email"></paper-input>
    <paper-input label="Password" type="password"></paper-input>
    <paper-button label="Login" affirmative></paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer({});
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

But the moment I import more than one dependency (in this case `paper-button` and `paper-input`, I get this error in the console:

```
Error: DuplicateDefinitionError: a type with name 'core-meta' is already registered
```

It's coming from `platform.js`.  Why is this error appearing?  The demos in the documentation work exactly the same, but they behave normally.

**Edit:** Updated to load with absolute URLs, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: This error will occur if `core-meta.html` is imported twice. This can happen if your application tries to import something from a folder other than whatever `../../bower_components` resolves to. The import de-duplication filter only works on full absolute URLs.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I'll try switching to absolute URLs.

Comment: @ScottMiles tried that, same result :(

Comment: The notion was not to _switch to absolute URLs_, it's to check your network tab (for example) and make sure that the URLs actually resolved are not referencing different paths. Iow, if you are loading `/foo/components/core-meta.html` and `/bar/components/core-meta.html` you will have this error.

Comment: @ScottMiles I checked the console and they're resolving to the same path.  Here is the log output: http://pastebin.com/mr48kX8p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All righty, I figured it out.  In my layout file, I was importing `core-component-page`.  That file contains a definition for `core-meta`, along with some other elements that are already satisfied dependencies.  I'm not sure why I had that in there, but I'd sure like to know what `core-component-page` is, and why it exists.

Comment: `core-component-page` is a specialized component which implements a configurable application for constructing an informational page from component meta-data. This component is _vulcanized_ (all dependencies are concatenated inside) to make it functional with no external dependencies. Polymer components come with an index html which load this component to generate a standard page (currently docs).

Comment: @ScottMiles okay, that really clears it up.  Thank you.